# How do I make a single lineplot line part solid and part dashed in seaborn?

Tags: python, seaborn

I'm making a line plot of data points plotted at yearly intervals. There was a single year when data was not collected. I'd like to make the part of the line that joins the previous and subsequent year dashed, to show that (with the rest of the line being solid).

I've seen this done but I can't figure out the appropriate code. Any advice much appreciated.

I'm using seaborn to make the figure but the dashes argument seems to only work for whole lines, not part of a line.

Comment: could you please share expected input/output ?

Comment: Plot two lines.

Answer (score 0):

you can create a line plot with a part solid and part dashed line by plotting multiple line segments with different line styles

Create two separate line plots for each `DataFrame`, specifying the line styles (solid and dashed) for each segment.

```
sns.lineplot(x='Year', y='Value', data=df1, label='Solid Part', linestyle='-', marker='o', markersize=8) 
sns.lineplot(x='Year', y='Value', data=df2, label='Dashed Part', linestyle='--', marker='o', markersize=8)
```